# Spring @Scheduled is trigged before the set time

Tags: java, spring, spring-scheduled

I made a simple method on my Spring application with the annotation @Schedled:

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0/10 * * * * ?")
@Async
public void trigger() {..//print "hello" here..}
```

I expect this method will be call for every 10 seconds. I think it'd be call at right after second 10*(0->5)th second.
But, I got the output:

```
2016-09-21 15:25:59,996 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-223] INFO  ....
2016-09-21 15:26:10,009 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-224] INFO  ....
2016-09-21 15:26:19,996 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-225] INFO  ....
2016-09-21 15:26:30,011 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-226] INFO  ....
2016-09-21 15:26:40,121 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-226] INFO  ....
```

Some of them were triggered at end the second *9th. 
Can anybody tell me that I misunderstand the concept of this or it's a bug?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think this tolerance of a few milliseconds for your log entry is normal. It's the time the log is written and not the time where the task got executed.

Comment: I would assume, that there is some discrepancy between time measurement for thread scheduling, and for logging output to a console. As far as I know, for task scheduling Spring uses the Quartz Scheduler ( http://quartz-scheduler.org). On the other side, logging relies on standard JVM time measurement mechanisms.

Comment: @HerrDerb, Tinki Thank you for your answers. I will investigate more.